# Using makefile with multiple C programs

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I've written multiple C programs in different files and I want to run all three of them in the same time, on the same argv:

That's what I tried so far but its only running the last program digcmp.c:

```
CC=gcc
a_OBJS=lexcmp.o
b_OBJS=lencmp.o
c_OBJS=digcmp.o
EXEC=lex len dig
DEBUG = -g
CFLAGS = -std=c99  -Wall -Werror $(DEBUG)  #if you have CFLAGS you do not have to write for each file $(CC) -c $*.c!!!

lex: $(b_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(a_OBJS) -o $@


len: $(b_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(b_OBJS) -o $@


dig: $(c_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(c_OBJS) -o $@


lexcmp.o: lexcmp.c
lencmp.o: lencmp.c
digcmp.o: digcmp.c


clean: 
    rm -f lex $(a_OBJS)
    rm -f len $(b_OBJS)
    rm -f dig $(c_OBJS)
```

Comment: What is the question?  What do you mean with "run all ... the same time"?  Why did you tag this with c and linux?  It's a make question as far as I can tell.

Comment: I want to run three different programs with the same make file. how can I do it? each program has its own 'main'

Comment: If you have three different programs, you need to create three different executable files. Right now you link all your programs into a single executable file, which of course won't work if each source/object file is supposed to be used to create separate and individual executable files.

Comment: Can you show me an example

Comment: How about a rule like `lexcmp: lexcmcp.o`?

Comment: Tried something look I edited the post. now I have another problem its only runs the last one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `make` program have many [*implicit rules*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html). In fact they are what makes your `lexcmp.o: lexcmp.c` (etc.) rules work.

All you need is to list the rules to make the executable programs themselves:

```
lexcmp: lexcmp.o
lencmp: lencmp.o
digcmp: digcmp.o
```

The above is a perfectly fine `Makefile` on its own, and if you run e.g.

```
$ make lencmp
```

then the `lencmp.c` source file will be built into the object file `lencmp.o` which will then be linked into the executable `lencmp` program.

If you want specific compilation flags when building just set the `CFLAGS` variable and it will be used automatically. I also recommend a default target which might list all executable targets as dependencies to build all of them:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra

.PHONY: all
all: lexcmp lencmp digcmp
```

This should really be enough to build all your executable files (skipping the object-file intermediate stage) with the flags you want.

[The `.PHONY` target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) tells `make` that it's not supposed to generate a file with the name `all`.